# Create user and give full access to database through sql in SQL Server 2000

Tags: sql, sql-server-2000

I have a program where I need to create a user through SQL and give them access to a database.  This program is run against SQL Server 2000.  I could have sworn the SQL was working when I wrapped up at the end of the day yesterday but it's not working today and I'm pulling my hair out trying to make it work.

```
use master
exec sp_addlogin @loginame='newLogin', @passwd='password', @defdb='theDB'
use theDB
exec sp_grantdbaccess newLogin, newLogin
grant all to newLogin
```

After running the SQL statements as "sa" I log in as the new user and try to select from any of the tables in the database and get

```
SELECT permission denied on object 'XXXX', database 'YYYY', owner 'dbo'
```

What am I missing?

Comment: If you truly want to give them full and potential destructive access, add them to the db_owner database role. I'm not sure what `GRANT ALL TO` means.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the user as a db_owner for the specific database seems to do the trick.